# Get variable from one Java class into GUI form Java class JLabel

Tags: java, swing, class, user-interface

I want to get `device connected: true` JLabel in DisplayForm.java GUI if I press the connectBtn in DisplayForm.java GUI, but I can't get the variable String connected = "true"; from ArduinoDisplay.java to DisplayForm.java connectedDevice JLabel when I press connectBtn in DisplayForm.java.

Part of ArduinoDisplay.java

```
    String connected = "";

    public void initialize() {
    if (portId == null) {
        System.out.println("Could not find COM port.");
        connected = "False";
        System.out.println("CONNECTED: " + connected + " PORT: " + devCom);
        return;
        } else if( portId != null) {
        connected = "True";
        System.out.println("CONNECTED: " + connected + " PORT: " + devCom);
        } else {
        connected = "False";
        System.out.println("CONNECTED: " + connected + " PORT: " + devCom);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ArduinoDisplay main = new ArduinoDisplay();
    main.initialize();


    // Start GUI
    DisplayForm gui = new DisplayForm();
    gui.setVisible(true);
}
```

Part of the DisplayForm.java

```
private void connectBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    ArduinoDisplay ad = new ArduinoDisplay();
    String devCon = ad.connected;
    deviceConnected.setText(devCon);
}
```

If more code is needed, let me know, thank you

Comment: are both classes in the same package?

Comment: Yes, both are in arduinodisplay package

Comment: the code you provided from ArduinoDisplay.java is executed before the button is clicked?

Comment: if is there really somthing about port, then you have an issue with Concurency in Swing, more in Oracle tutorial with the same name, 2-10times daily asked questions with EDT issue

Comment: MihailBurduja, I request DisplayForm to be set to visible in ArduinoDisplay, so yeah, ArduinoDisplay is run before the button is clicked.. 
@mKorbel what do you mean by"if there is really something about port?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the connected variable outside of any method and do not allow direct access to it (use a getter method)

```
public class ArduinoDisplay {
    private String connected = "false":


public String getConnected (){
    return this.connected;
}
....
}
```

and get it like this:

```
private void connectBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    ArduinoDisplay ad = new ArduinoDisplay();
    String devCon = ad.getConnected();
    deviceConnected.setText(devCon);
}
```

**Side Note**: try to use boolean instead of a String. Or Enum's if you need several states. It saves you time and eliminates developer typo's

Comment: Awesome, thank you for this, still one question, the portId is checked within public void initialize(), how could I get it from there?

Comment: everything created inside a method stays inside a method. Where do you get the value for portID?

Comment: Inside the same method.

Comment: If you want to access a variable outside a method, create it outside of a method. SO do the same thing as with connected | getConnected();

Comment: Ok, that worked indeed, But this way I will get the same code over and over again in ArduinoDisplay. Anyways, for now it's good enough, prototype purposes. Thank you